# Font Awesome list padding

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am having some difficulties with the Font Awesome list markers. I am using the solution provided in docs:

```css
ul li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: dotted 1px #222;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><i class="fa fa-li fa-check-square"></i>List Item</li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-li fa-check-square"></i>List Item</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fknfe8xq/)

The problem is with the padding. If I set padding on the `<li>` element, the `<i>` element does not receive the padding setting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icons will not respect padding if you apply `.fa-li` class, because in this case they become absolutely positioned. What you can do however is to position them vertically to `50%` and then shift them a little back by the half of the height with negative translate:

```
.fa-li {
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/fknfe8xq/1/

Comment: yes, this works in the fiddle, but for some reason it won't work when i use it on the drupal page which i am editing. i guess that's a completely new question though.

Comment: Make sure your CSS comes after font-awesome styles.

Comment: Hm, in this case you can try to replicate the issue in fiddle or dive a link to your website. Or open developer tools and try to find out what styles are applied and in what order.

Answer (score 1):

You must set same top/bottom paddings for `ul li` and `ul li i`.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fknfe8xq/2/)

```
ul li {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #222;
}

ul li i {
    padding: 10px 0px;
}
```

Comment: No problem. Not forget, `transform` not working in old browser (this is my comment about accepted answer). If You have any questions, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Add `,i` to your CSS code:

```
ul li, i {
padding: 10px 0;
border-bottom: dotted 1px #222;
}
```

This will apply the padding CSS for the `ul li` to the `i` as well.

**Working JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/joe_young/q4Lzrvnf/

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. the problem here is that the icon gets the border as well, however i could single it out. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected as the icons are absolutely positioned relative to the ul container.So they wont be styled.You will have to style it separately.

```
i {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: the problem with this solution is that it does not align well. i found that in the fiddle the margin which worked best was 7px, while on the drupal page which i am editing i had to add 15px. weird stuff.